# merging two elements of two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

Hello Everyone I have a Array in php like

```
        array (size=2)
        0 => string 'A6,A5,B12,B11,' (length=14)
        1 => string 'B6,B5,B8,B7,' (length=12)
```

on var_dump($arr). How could I convert it to something like

```
        array('A6,A5,B12,B11,B6,B5,B8,B7,')
```

in php.
here is what i'm doing eaxctly to get the above array

```
 $id= "1";

 $data['busInfo']= $this->dashboard_model->find_bus($id);

 $data['reservationInfo'] = $this->dashboard_model->get_booked_seats_info($id);
 $arr =array();
 foreach ($data['reservationInfo'] as $reserved){
     $seatBooked = $reserved->seats_numbers; 
     array_push($arr, $seatBooked);  
 }
 var_dump($arr);
```

I'm using Codeigniter as my framework.

Comment: If you're trying to create a long string, you don't need to use an array. Create a string, `$str`, and append `$seatBooked` to the string (`$str .= $seatBooked`) instead of pushing it on to $arr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just append to a string, then create a single element array with that string (if you actually need an array):

```
$data['reservationInfo'] = $this->dashboard_model->get_booked_seats_info($id);
$str='';
foreach ($data['reservationInfo'] as $reserved){
     $str .= $reserved->seats_numbers;  
}
var_dump(array($str));
```

Or just implode the source array:

```
var_dump(array(implode('', $this->dashboard_model->get_booked_seats_info($id))));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my time, it worked as i wanted